# Ruby Colorize gem - Is there a method to get the color name from a colorized string?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, colorize

I'd like to get the name preferably, or the code of a colorized string.

For example:

`"Hello".red.color
=> "red" or :red`

I can use regular expressions but want to make sure there isn't already a quick way to do this.  Thanks.

Comment: Since a string can contain various colors and decorations, a `color` method doesn't seem to make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `"Hello".colorize(:red)` returns a string, I don't see it possible. A regex for specific color may be a good approach.

Private function `scan_for_colors` https://github.com/fazibear/colorize/blob/7c0b50a278da01870be4435ec1b5753c2544e8f3/lib/colorize/instance_methods.rb#L108 is a good start point ...

UPDATE:

This solution can work with some colors...

```
String.colors.find{|x| stringToCheck.colorize(x) === stringToCheck}
```

Comment: Since ruby got an aspect-like [`Module#prepend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-prepend), it might be easily done, see my answer.

Comment: This solution works nicely for my purposes.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Re-monkeypatch it!

```
Colorize::InstanceMethods.prepend(Module.new do # surround colorize
  def colorize(params)
    super(params).extend(Module.new do # extend the returned string
      def __color__
        params
      end
    end)
  end
end)
```

*NB:* the code is untested, but it should work.

Comment: Where should I put this code?  BTW, I'm getting a syntax error on line 2 `unexpected keyword_def, expecting ')'`.  Thanks.

Comment: Anywhere (syntax error fixed, I have updated an answer, there was missing `do`.)

Comment: Ok, it runs now but there is a scope issue for `params`.  It is undefined when `__color__` is invoked.  I tried saving it into `@params` above the super line and then access that instance variable in `__color__` but it returns nil.  Lastly, I think this solution would only work for chained invocation immediately after invoking `colorize`.  It would not work in this this example:
`s = "hi";
s.colorize(:red);
s.__color_`
Unless I am missing something..